# How to assign 'any' type to a object property in realm schema in react native?

Tags: javascript, database, typescript, react-native, realm

I have an api response which is coming based on fieldType, so I can not give any particular type to schema.

response type 1 (fieldType = polygon):

```
[[[11.4354534,73.23423],[11.4354534,73.23423],[11.4354534,73.23423]...]]
```

response type 2(fieldType = line):

```
[[11.4354534,73.23423],[11.4354534,73.23423],[11.4354534,73.23423]...]
```

Now I want to assign above response type to schema COORDINATES , but as we do not have any fixed type of response , I am planning to assign type any to the schema.

**Schema:**

```
const FieldSchemaNames = {
 .....
....
  COORDINATES:'any',
 ....
....
};
```

but here **any** is not working . Do we have any types for schema.

**any** type - Whatever value we will assign to that attribute , it will accept-.

Comment: Can you hare all scheme of realm?

Comment: The question is pretty unclear so it's going to be difficult to answer. What do the array's in the question have to do with the presented Schema? The array's are actually arrays of sub arrays (assuming they are arrays) so their tie in to whatever your's asking is no obvious. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I just wanted to assign 'any' type to the schema attributes instead of 'string' , 'object' , 'list'...etc . Do we have such options ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that is currently supported, but is in the latest beta release (10.5.0-beta.2). You can find the issue tracking it [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/3389). As for syntax, it's using `mixed` instead of `any`:

```
const FieldSchemaNames = {
    ....
    COORDINATES:'mixed',
    .... 
};
```